# Show div depending on input And position Property with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').focusin(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
      // If not empty value, show div
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#div').show();
      } else {
        $('#div').hide();
      }    
    });
  });
  $('#input').focusout(function() {
    $('#div').hide();

  });

});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

In my code here, While typing it shows a div, And hide it if not typing, Before setting the `position: absolute, bottom: 20px;` the links was clickable and doesn't disappear onclick, But now it doesn't

Comment: you need to close your `a` tags

Comment: Your javascript is hiding your div when the input loses focus.

Comment: You have div hide event on focusout of input when you click on anchor focus will out & cause to hide div.  Test it by removing that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st not sure why you need the focusout, but what you can do is to add a small delay (50ms) to hide stuff so you got the small window when you click the link:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#div').hide();
}, 50);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').focusin(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
      // If not empty value, show div
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#div').show();
      } else {
        $('#div').hide();
      }
    });
  });
  $('#input').focusout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#div').hide();
    }, 50);
  });

});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

Comment: but he want to hide link if not typing

Comment: @Omi then add a delay to focusout to hide stuff, so you got the time period of click

Comment: That solved the problem, But isn't there a  decent  way to do that? Like users want to drag & drop the links to order them in different ways?